# Is there a way to pass time other than sleeping in a bed?

Tags: risen-2

I'm stuck running around in the wilderness barely able to see anything. I know you can sleep in a bed but there isn't any around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately **there is no waiting** like there is in TES games.However did you think about using a **torch**? They are easy to find and you usually have bunch of them with you if you don't sell them.

Other than that you can stay in "safe" spot and **wait** until game time changes.

You could usually **fast travel few times** between 2 distant locations but you need map and 2 locations discovered for that,and I don't think this will help your situation much since you are in middle of jungle.This method is best in case you can't find any beds.